# Processing - three-line text editor and move to next line?

Tags: processing

I need to write a typing program to create a “three-line” text editor. If the length of the
input string is longer than the line (40 characters), it will be automatically move to
the next line.

This is my code so far:

```java
String word = "";

void setup() {
    size(1000, 600);
    textSize(26);
    fill(0);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    text(word, 0, 0, width, height);
}

void keyPressed() {
    int lineBreak = word.length();
    if(lineBreak > 39) {
        word = word + "\n"; 
    }
    else {
        word = word + key;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the problem, the string length stops at 40 characters but it doesn't move to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

[`text()`](https://processing.org/reference/text_.html) does not support line breaks.
You have to store each line to a separate string. For instance use [`StringList`](https://processing.org/reference/StringList.html) to store the lines of the text.

Create an array of strings, that stores the finished lines. The current line is still stored in `word`:

```java
StringList lines = new StringList();
```

When the line limit is reached, then add the line to the list and start a new line:

```java
if(lineBreak > 39) {
    lines.append(word);
    word = ""; 
}
```

Define a `lineheight` an draw the lines in a loop. The vertical position of a line is computed by `lineheight * (i + 1)`, where `i` is the index of the line:

```java
int lineheight = 30;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String line = lines.get(i);
    text(line, 0, lineheight * (i + 1));
}
text(word, 0, lineheight * (lines.size() + 1));
```

See the example:

```java
StringList lines = new StringList();
String word = "";

void setup() {
    size(1000, 600);
    textSize(26);
    fill(0);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);

    int lineheight = 30;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);
        text(line, 0, lineheight * (i + 1));
    }
    text(word, 0, lineheight * (lines.size() + 1));
}

void keyPressed() {
    int lineBreak = word.length();
    if(lineBreak > 39) {
        lines.append(word);
        word = ""; 
    }
    else {
        word += key;
    }
}
```